# Probability Deducing knowledge about relationship between compound events knowing the values of their conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image: Consider the following probability tree]

- The values of α1 and α2 can help derive knowledge about the relationship between events A and B: if α1 = α2 ⇒ P(B\A) = P(B\Ā) = P(B) ⇒ A and B are independent.
- What do the values of ß1, ß2, ß3, and ß4 tell me? In other words, what would be the relationship between ß1, ß2, ß3, and ß4 in the following 16 scenarios.

$\boxed{\begin{array}{|l|r|}\hline
\text{Scenario}&01&02&03&04&05&06&07&08&09&10&11&12&13&14&15&16\\
\hline
B\text{ and }A &I &I &I &I &I &I &I &I &D &D &D &D &D &D &D &D \\\hdashline 
C\text{ and }A &I &I &I &I &D &D &D &D &I &I &I &I &D &D &D &D \\\hdashline
C\text{ and }B &I &I &D &D &I &I &D &D &I &I &D &D &I &I &D &D \\\hdashline
C\text{ and }AB&I &D &I &D &I &D &I &D &I &D &I &D &I &D &I &D \\
\hline\end{array}}$

I denoting independence and D denoting dependence

- Can some of those scenarios not even exist (e.g can C be dependent on AB while it is independent from both A and B individually: scenarios 2 and 10).

Please let me know if my question is unclear, I tried posting once before, and I didn't the needed help because my question was confusing and erroneous (I am to blame).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.